# open popup and save information in the parent page with struts

Tags: javascript, popup, struts-1

i am new in struts developing a Java EE application in struts 1.3 i have a requirement that i had a parent page with button 'popup' which opens a popup window which contains the form(input fields) . and the child window contains a button 'Save'
on Save

2)close the child window
3)display data in tabular form in the parent page
Can you give me any idéa please.

Answer (score 0):

**Your child jsp should look something like below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveInParent(){
        window.close();
        window.opener.location.href="parentAction.do";
    }
</script>

<html:form onsubmit="return saveInParent();">
    <html:text property="name"></html:text>
    <input type="submit">Save </input>
</html:form>
```

**You parent jsp:**

```
<html:form action="/parentAction">
    <html:text property="name"></html:text>
</html:form>
```

Make sure you're using the same action class for both the child window and the parent window. This way you're setting the value of "name" property in child window and displaying it in parent window.